# notifyDataSetChanged and PagerTitleStrip

Tags: android, adapter, android-viewpager

I use a FragmentAdapter to populate a Viewpager with a PagerTitleStrip (using getTitle() in the Adapter).

All is working fine (at least for now) except one thing, when i update the title of one of the fragment and i call notifyDataSetChanged in the adapter , the title in the PagerTitleStrip change but not the size of textview that hold it, eg:

[image: first picture for eg]

then i update after clicking to a folder

[image: second picture fo eg]

as you can see , the Notification title isn't complete because the textview is still at the size of sdcard0.

When i swipe to another fragment (left or right), as soon as the swipe begin , the size of the textview is updated.

Does anyone know what can i do to update it at the same time as the title change?

Comment: Is Notification title is wrap_content ?

Comment: How can I know that? I don't interact directly with the PagerTitleStrip

Comment: Please post your code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround to update the textview size.
I call pagerStrip.setTextSpacing(pagerStrip.getTextSpacing()); to set the text space at the same value.

it's not perfect but its working!

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the exact same problem.

Edit: Here is the solution, it was so easy...

```
ViewPager mViewPager;
PagerTitleStrip pagerTitleStrip;

mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

pagerTitleStrip = (PagerTitleStrip) findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);

mViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
pagerTitleStrip.setTextSpacing(pagerTitleStrip.getTextSpacing());
```